# PostgreSQL - can not figure out how to relate tables for certain task

Tags: sql, postgresql, reference, foreign-key-relationship

I have a table `beverage` that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE beverage (
    beverage_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
    beverage    TEXT UNIQUE NOT NULL,
    description TEXT,
    sizeprice_id NOT NULL REFERENCES sizeprice ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

I want to use a referencing column `sizeprice_id` within the `beverage` table to prevent adding beverages without specifying a 'prize per size'.

Furthermore these rules should apply:

1. One `beverage` can have multiple sizes
2. One `beverage` in a certain `size` can only have one `price` - if (Coke,
   0.3, 2.50) exists one can not add a row (Coke, 0.3, 5.00)

**Examples:**

```
+----------+-------------+------+-------+
| beverage | description | size | price |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+
| Coke     | NULL        | 0.3  | 2.50  |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+
| Coke     | NULL        | 0.5  | 3.00  |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+
| Sprite   | small       | 0.2  | 2.00  |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+
| Sprite   | medium      | 0.3  | 2.75  |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+
| Sprite   | large       | 0.5  | 3.50  |
+----------+-------------+------+-------+
```

I'm not quite sure how to achieve that. I have been using a table with `PRIMARY KEY (beverage_id, size, price)` but that does not really work as a certain `beverage` could have different `price`s for one `size`. Also I had a reference from table `beverages` to table `sizeprice` and vice versa, reference loops should be avoided according to google.

I assume I do need more than one table to make it work as needed, probably have to split `sizeprice` into two tables `size` and `prize`. I was fiddling around with a FK in `beverage` that references a 1:M relation table `size` (one beverage can have several sizes), and that was referencing another table `prize` but I couldn't get that quite working either.

How do I achieve what I want?

**EDIT:**
[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ebb0f/3)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd want a table beverage_types with columns `type_id`, `name` so you don't end up with products name "Coke", "coke" and "COKE". 
Also a table sizes with columns `size_id`, `description`, `size`.
Finally that gives you a table `beverage` with columns `id`,`type_id`,`size_id` with FKs on `type_id` and `size_id`. 
Now you just enforce one price per size per type with a `UNIQUE INDEX`.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX size_price_idx ON beverage (type_id,size_id);
```

Comment: Oh, I just realized that I will have to use CITEXT instead of TEXT. I did not know that UNIQUE can be used over multiple columns at once! Thank you!

Comment: I have tried your approach and it does not work. Maybe I misunderstood you. Here is what I have been working with: [SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/ebb0f/3)

Comment: @phew Well yeah, I shouldn't have added the third column. You however haven't used the index at all: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/27811/2

Comment: Ahh! Now I see what I was supped to do but failed. Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I was looking for!